# How to properly store GMT offset?

Tags: php, timezone, gmt

So recently I stored all my locations with their GMT offset as integers (-12 to 12) and everything was ok, but now I have to add more locations, and I noticed that some of them are in timezones with GMT +05:30 and even +05:45. How do you store these? Like +5.5 or 5.75?

Regards,
Briedis

Comment: The problem with storing the offset for a location is that it can vary.  Consider daylight savings time. If you store the timezone (e.g. America/New York) then PHP DateTime objects can figure out the correct offset at the time it is needed.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I already use php to get the correct time depending on DST.

Comment: except that's impossible when you've thrown away the actual time zone information (which is much, much more complex than a simple offset, minute granularity or not).

Comment: @Michael, I didn't say I don't store the timezones' identifier. I store it too and use it to check if DST is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple: Don't do it. Store the related timezone name (e.g. "Europe/Berlin") instead of the GMT offset ("GMT+1").

Comment: I store timezones identifier too, but I need the offset for some astrological calculations. Eh, now I came to conclusion that I actually have problems with the astrological software that accepts gmt offset as a number.

Comment: @Briedis: it only accepts integers? Ignorance about this is amazingly common. The EXIF header format also has a timezone offset field defined as integer...

Comment: @Michael, I dug deeper in the source code of the software, and it seems that it accepts floats, atleast it checks if the fraction is greater or lesser than 5. I'll stick to storing as a float (decimal), but still use the timezones name to represent it to user.

Answer (score 1):

The common format for that is `shhmm` where `s` is the sign, `hh` are hours and `mm` are minutes (e.g., `+0530` or `-0500`).

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to store Datetime as UTC and store the offset as Time, so you can always refer back to the correct Datetime in history by adjusting it with the offset.  You can also store the time zone in a third field so you know which time zone it came from.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a second integer column for minute offset, with default of 0 since it will be for the majority of entries.